# How can I Bluetooth-pair with a Pioneer C9P5 head unit?

Tags: mazda, bluetooth

This is a '09 Mazda Axela. The language is in Japanese, need English.

I don't know how to pair Bluetooth with my phone because I don't understand any Japanese. Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you checked the pioneer website to see if they do the instruction manual in English?

Comment: Have you tried a service like (or similar to) Google Translate? You can probably scan Japanese text, and have the service present you with machine-translated English.